# Adding field with geometry in WKT format in QGIS

Tags: qgis-3, attribute-table, geometry, fields-attributes, well-known-text

I have a shapefile with polygons and want to add an attribute field with the WKT in QGIS 3.4.

The function `geom_to_wkt()` in the Field Calculator isn't working and I don't know how to do it. Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE ! Have you tried to update with : `geom_to_wkt( $geometry )` ?

Comment: Make sure you use a _string_ field type with a high length.

Comment: I have complex polygons with long wkt. How do I know how big the new field "wkt" has to be?? With 254 length most of the wkt are incomplete.

Comment: Just use an other format gpkg for example. Shapefile is limited to 254 characters, no way to change this...

Comment: Please, do not forget about ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 8):

You need to both (i) create a new string attribute with a high character limit and (ii) use the field calculator to convert the geometry to its WKT representation.

Use the field calculator as shown in the screenshots below to do this (select what is here "Neues Feld anlegen" instead of "Vorhandenes Feld erneuern" to create a new attribute for the results of the calculation):

[image: field calculator for new text field]

The field will hold the geometry as seen in the preview above:

[image]

With Python/PyQGIS, the same approach would look as follows:

```py
params = {
'INPUT' : <input layer / file path for input layer>,
'FIELD_NAME' : "WKT",
'FIELD_TYPE' : 2, # String
'FIELD_LENGTH' : 100, # String character limit
'NEW_FIELD' : 1, # 1 = new field, 0 = existing field
'FORMULA' : 'geom_to_wkt( $geometry )', # formula
'OUTPUT' : <file path for output layer>
}
processing.run('qgis:fieldcalculator', params)
```

Answer (score 4):

Another solution implies the usage of a ["Virtual Layer"](https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/managing_data_source/create_layers.html#creating-virtual-layers) through `Layer > Add Layer > Add/Edit Virtual Layer...`.

Let's assume there is a polygon layer *'districts'* with its attribute table accordingly, see image below.

[image: input]

With the following query it is possible *to add a field with geometry in WKT format*

```sql
SELECT *, geom_to_wkt(geometry) AS wkt
FROM "districts"
```

The output Virtual Layer will maintain original geometry and all initial attributes including a new, namely `"wkt"`.

[image: output_1]

The alternative query will contain [`ST_AsText()`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_AsText.html) parameter.

> It returns the Well-Known Text representation of the geometry/geography.
> Optional argument may be used to reduce the maximum number of decimal
> digits after floating-point used in the output (defaults to 15).

```sql
SELECT *, ST_AsText(geometry) AS wkt
FROM "districts"
```

[image: output_2]